# How change PATH env in cmd.exe /c in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path, environment-variables

I want run something like this:

```
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%Path%"" & ECHO. %Path% & PAUSE"
```

But there is a problem: the command line window appears only for a moment, then disappears. I create a test .bat (like `echo.1: %1` and 2,3...) to check out how it behave and...

```
0: "V:\test.bat"
1: /c
2: "set ""Path=V:\;
3: 
(4-9 the same)
```

When I replace % with for example 5, second argument look like `"set ""Path=V:\;5Path5"" & ECHO. 5Path5 & PAUSE"`, but it is not what I want.
I think, there may be problem with parsing %Path% inside this shell command.

I tried aslo:

```
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%%Path%%"" & ECHO. %%Path%% & PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%%%Path%%%"" & ECHO. %%%Path%%% & PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%%%%Path%%%%"" & ECHO. %%%%Path%%%% & PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%%%%%Path%%%%%"" & ECHO. %%Path%%%%% & PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%%%%%%%%Path%%%%%%%%"" & ECHO. %%%%%%%%Path%%%%%%%% & PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;^%Path^%"" &ECHO.^%Path^%&PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;^%%Path^%%"" &ECHO.^%Path^%&PAUSE"
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;\%Path\%"" &ECHO.\%Path\%&PAUSE"
```

I will editing post during my next tests...

Edit:
I just noticed that I cannot even use simply: `cmd /c "echo %PATH% & PAUSE"`

Comment: After further tests, I suspect that the problem is I cannot pass string containing `%path%` (and `%windir%` and some other, NOT ALL env vars) outside cmd line window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come to the solution. What I needed:

```
cmd /c "set ""Path=V:\;%Path:~0%"" &ECHO.%Path:~0%&PAUSE"
```

It's look like Windows replace `%PATH%` with this env-variable content (more paths by semicolons), even in Run (Win+R), CMD (.exe), ShellExec (wscript/winapi). So it can not be used as part of argument in shortcut (i needed to).

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to work because xx is evaluated before cmd is started

```
cmd /c "set xx=yyyyyy & echo %xx% & PAUSE"
```

That proves that it works, the variable is properly set:

```
cmd /c "set xx=yyyyyy & set xx & PAUSE"
```

output:

```
xx=yyyyyy
```

Other way to escape the `%`:

```
cmd /c "set xx=yyyyyy & ECHOxx.bat & PAUSE"
```

(`ECHOxx.bat` is a script which does `echo %xx%`)

output

```
yyyyyy
```

For the path, it's slightly complex as you noticed yourself, but it works fine too:

```
cmd /c "set PATH=%CD%\subdir;"%PATH%" & echoxx.bat"
```

it works: `echoxx.bat` had been moved in the `subdir` directory, and it is found.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere... It looks like I cannot use `%PATH%` string as part of param passed to `cmd /c`.

Comment: I just figured it out.

Comment: I still cannot use change PATH that way (I have tried `cmd /c "set Path=V:\;%Path% &ECHO.%Path%&PAUSE"`), because it cannot let me use `%PATH%`.

Comment: Aslo, `%PATH%` must be in quotes in this case, because it contains paths with spaces.

Comment: `echo %PATH%` will still display the old path because it is evaluated before CMD starts, but my last edit proves that the path is actually updated.

Comment: Still it break on `%PATH%`. I just tried `cmd /c "set PATH=V:\"%PATH%" & PAUSE"`. Using more quotes with `%PATH%` doesn't help.

Comment: That is because you forgot the semicolon, path does not work on V asyou expected

Comment: Can you tell which version of Windows you're using?

Comment: It looks like Windows is so shity that it replace `%PATH%` with it's content... I come to the solution of my problem: `v:\test.bat /c "set ""Path=V:\;%Path:~0%"" &ECHO.%Path:~0%&PAUSE"`, but there is left question... How pass `%PATH%` string to any batch/program? ("%path%", not the env variable content.

Comment: for that double the `%`.

Comment: I tried every thing - nothing helps. I must use `%PATH:~0%`